# No record returned from SQL table although the data was there

Tags: c#, sql

It happened couple of times in PROD DB.

The below query didn't return record in production DB so the transaction got failed.

```
SELECT  Id, candoid, c3.clientname
        FROM    client_data c1 (NOLOCK)
        JOIN    client_data c3 (NOLOCK) ON c1.clientid  = c3.TopclientID
        JOIN    Main_program    p  (NOLOCK) ON c3.clientid  = p.clientid
        JOIN    sub_program     sp (NOLOCK) ON p.pgmid  = sp.pgmid
        WHERE                   c1.clientname   = 'HSBC'
        AND                 (sp.description = 'New HSBC' AND sp.Id =98752)
```

But the record was there always and it worked well in the past and its working now.
It return no value, then corresponding error code assigned and error raised back to the calling application which is written in C# .Net.

Only clue I have is, during this flow, the client_data..client_name was updated before reaching the above query, that could be the problem? but I tried to simulate in DEV, but no luck.

Any hint/help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: It -could- be that there was a table lock going on, with that update. Do you have any log files by any chance?

Comment: You are querying data with `NOLOCK` hints. Dirty reads are inconsistent reads. There are countless ways this query can return no data. The data will be neither 'there' nor 'not there'. The **committed** data is certinly there, but you're not reading *that*.

Comment: @WynDiesel  Unfortunately there are no detailed logs, the log just contains the error message retrieved from the stored proc. The table lock can cause the select statement to return no rows? how can I replicate this?

Comment: See also: [Bad habits: putting `NOLOCK` everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/AaronBertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/). Essentially, treat `NOLOCK` as a way of saying "I don't care if the results are correct at all". It's very rarely what you want, save for monitoring scenarios (where you don't care if the data is wrong, as you're going to be re-reading it soon anyway) and even then only if you don't intend to make decisions based on the (possibly) incorrect data. The fact that *most* of the time you won't see problems while it appears to resolve deadlocks makes `NOLOCK` extra insidious.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I agree the commit didn't happen yet, but most of the time its working, this issue is happening very rarely and I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @sivakumar. I would recommend reading this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and then also https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/. I'ts not an easy/short answer I can give in a comment.

Comment: @sivakumar. My apologies, I didn't answer you question correctly; my answer was more to do with isolation level. Without seeing the total scope of your code, and where/how/when the query is called, it will be near impossible to answer your question .By the symptoms you're experiencing, I would say its race condition, that involves a table lock. Can I recommend rather starting a new question, with the calling code around this query, and asking if it could cause a table lock?

Comment: @WynDiesel I have gone thru the links provided, I understand that read uncommitted lock could be the reason. Also I see that the C# code handles transaction SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction(); before calling the stored proc for performing sequence of actions (client update and then reaching the above query).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree with you, in my org, if there is a select statement then by default Nolock will be added, we think that using Nolock will prevent locking the table while performing the read operation, so thats not true?

Comment: `NOLOCK` means, no more and no less, "read this data under the `READ UNCOMMITTED` serialization level rules". `NOLOCK` does not mean "take no locks at all", despite the name -- it still issues metadata locks, for starters. What is true is that it will not issue row locks, or even data stability locks. The linked article clearly explains why using `NOLOCK` as a mindless default is a bad idea, and possible alternatives.